# YOUTUBE XML FEED - getting description of video

Tags: xml, youtube

im having this code:
And I need to parse description of video somehow. Can anyone help me? Im kinda new in this problematics. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<style type="text/css">
/* placeholder inline styles */

body { font-family: arial, verdana; }

a,
a img { text-decoration: none; }

ul.youtubeFeed {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

ul.youtubeFeed li {
float: left;
width: 150px;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 11px;
height: 170px;
}

ul.youtubeFeed li div { width: 118px; }
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
// setup the click handler
function loadVideo(video) {

$('#videos h3').text(video.title);

$('#youtubeVideo').html([
'<iframe title="', video.title, '" width="560" height="349" src="', video.href, '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
].join(""));
return false;
}

// get the feed info
// setting max-results delivers you the maximum of 50, you can remove to default to 25. Use feed.setNumEntries to strip down to a range between 50 and 25.
var feedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/84FBB60DFE42481F?max-results=50";
new google.feeds.lookupFeed(feedUrl, function (result) {
if (result.error || !result.url) {
$('#videocomm').hide();
return;
}
// get the feed items
var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(result.url);
feed.setNumEntries(50);
feed.load(function (result) {
// write out the feed data
var container = $(".youtubeFeed");
//var totalcount = result.feed.entries.length;
//alert (totalcount);

for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
var vidhash = /=(.*)&(.*)$/.exec (entry.link)[1];
// uncomment this and comment out the item below if you find rendering of the player a bit slow
// container.append('<li><div><a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+vidhash+'&feature=youtube_gdata&rel=1" class="yt-vid-link" title="'+entry.title+'"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidhash+'/2.jpg" /><br />'+entry.title+'</a></div></li>\n');

// comment the item below and uncomment the item above if you find the player swap too slow
container.append('<li><div><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+vidhash+'" class="yt-vid-link" title="'+entry.title+'"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidhash+'/2.jpg" /><br />'+entry.title+'</a></div></li>\n');
}
// load the first video
$(".yt-vid-link:first").each(function () {
loadVideo(this);
return false;
});
// setup the click handler for all the videso
$(".yt-vid-link").click(function () {
loadVideo(this);
return false;
});
});
});
});
google.load("feeds", "1");
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="videos">

<div id="videocomm">

<h3>Please Wait....</h3>

<div id="youtubeVideo">

Insert video here

</div>

<p>Click a thumbnail below to watch the video.</p>

<div class="slider">

<div id="fragment-1">

<ul class="youtubeFeed">

</ul>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And I need to parse description of video somehow. Can anyone help me? Im kinda new in this problematics. Thanks.